# Java - Cut a String from the right side till specific character

Tags: java, string, cut

I have the following String with a file path like that:

> /Users/Fabian/Desktop/R5X5.mps

I do now want to just geht the filename meaning - everything from the right side till '/'.

> In that case: R5X5.mps

What would be the most efficient way to do that ?

Can this be resolved with native java methods or do I need to build an regular expression ?

Comment: what about `s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/'), s.length())`? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: If it's always a file path, it might be easiest to `new File(yourString)` and then `file.getName()`

Comment: It nearly works the output then is: /R5X5.mps

Comment: @ale64bit Or just `s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`.

Comment: @Andreas Definitely! How did I miss that? :) Thx.

Comment: @FabiCho "it nearly works ..." => epic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex. It's pretty straightforward:

```
String last = str.replaceAll(".*/", "");
```

This regex says "everything up and including a slash", which gets replaced by nothing (effectively "deleting" it).

I don't think anyone would use the word "building" to describe the effort required to type `".*/"`.

Comment: Bit of an overkill when `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)` can do it. Works even if no `/` exists in the string, same as the `replaceAll()`.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for!

Comment: @Andreas why is it overkill? It's less code than your suggested approach and this code takes less than 2 microseconds to execute. What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> I do now want to just geht the filename meaning

Use proper class for that. Java offers for instance:

```
String name = new File("/Users/Fabian/Desktop/R5X5.mps").getName();
```

You can also achieve similar result with

```
String path = "/Users/Fabian/Desktop/R5X5.mps";
String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") +1); // "+1" since we don't
                                                        // want to include `/` in result
```

(which is essentially what `File#getName` does)

Comment: isn't the parameter to `lastIndexOf` a `char`?

Comment: @ale64bit Not quite, `lastIndexOf` accepts two types of parameters: `int` which would represent Unicode code point of character (we can also pass `char` like `'/'` here and let compiler treat it as `int`), or `String` like in this example.

Comment: @ale64bit Can be `char` (codepoint `int` actually) or `String`. Both works, but `char` would be better here (faster).

Comment: @Pshemo mmm, since Java 8. Good to know.

Comment: @ale64bit what do you mean by "since Java 8"? `lastIndexOf(String)` is in Java at least since 1.4.2 (https://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/) and I am not sure if it wasn't there form the beginning (after farther searching I found this 1.0.2 documentation http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Pshemo You are absolutely right :) Here's what happened: I open the link you posted in your comment, clicked in the first `lastIndexOf` I found, which is the one accepting `char`, without looking to the other variants, and then in the list of the detailed methods, it turns out that they are not sorted by name, so I assumed that those two variants were the only ones. Funny.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using [FilenameUtils.getName(String filename)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getName(java.lang.String)) is the best way. The `FilenameUtils` class is a part of [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

According to the documentation, the method "will handle a file in either Unix or Windows format".  "The text after the last forward or backslash is returned" as a String object.

```
String filename = "/Users/Fabian/Desktop/R5X5.mps";
String name = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
System.out.println(name);
```

The above code prints `R5X5.mps`.